# Navigate to external url on button click in LWC

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, navigationmixin.navigate

I have created a quick action button with LWC , Now on clicking the quick action button , the LWC should gather some field value from Account object and then redirect to the external URL.

I Created a wire method to get the custom field details now in order to do the navigation , could you guide me how I can do it because user will just click on the quick action button and i dont need to create another button in LWC for a click to redirect.

I couldnt use connectedcallback() as wired method data is not available in connectedcallback()

```
@wire(getJSONValue, { AccId: '$SFAccId' })
wiredSessions({ error, data }){
if (data) {
        this.navItem = data;
}
```

Next I tried appending a navigation mix method inside the wire method like below , but still I get the error as '**This page isn't available in Salesforce Lightning Experience or mobile app.'**

```
@wire(getJSONValue, { AccId: '$SFAccId' })
wiredSessions({ error, data }) {
    if (data) {
        this.navItem = data;
        this.error = undefined;
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            "type": "standard__webPage",
            "attributes": {
                "url": "https://www.salesforcecodecrack.com/"
            }
        });
        }
    }
```

Can you guide me how I do the redirect without creating an extra button in LWC or any better approach